# Do the property of $f_n$ carry over to $f_n'$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Suppose a sequence of differentiable functions $f _ { n } : \mathbb { R } \rightarrow [ 0,1 ]$ converges pointwise to the zero function. Does it follow that the derivatives $f _ { n } ^ { \prime }$ converge pointwise to the zero function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! 
Consider $$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{n}}$$ on $\Bbb R$. Here each $f_n$ is **infinitely differentiable** and  $f_n$ converges pointwise (actually uniformly) to zero. But $$f_n'(x)=\sqrt{n} \cos nx$$ is divergent at each $x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Interesting. How were you able to come up with that counter example?

Comment: This is a standard example and it appears in many texts. for example refer baby rudin

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't use Rudin's book and never saw this example. Do you know how one would prove that there does exist some counter example if one did not know this off the top of their head?

Comment: remember, you make the pointwise convergence as zero. Also you know $1/n, 1/n^2,...,1/ \sqrt{n}$ are all converges to zero. so  construct $f_n$ such as $$f_n(x)=\frac{?}{n}\;\;\text{or}\;\;\frac{?}{\sqrt{n}}\;\;\text{or}\;\;\frac{?}{n^2}\;\text{or}\;\;\frac{?}{\sqrt{1+n}} \cdots$$ Also make numerator as differentiable and bounded with its derivative is not differentiable

Comment: For example, $$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$$ is another counterexample to your statement!

Comment: Actually make suitable numerator to construct such a function

Comment: @Mohammed Shahid : Intuitively, try to think about how you'd make something that shrinks to a horizontal line while becoming ever more sharply-crinkled as it does so. The crinkles need to become sharper (increasing the maximum derivative) while simultaneously becoming smaller in peak-to-trough height (so the whole thing pointwise approaches 0).

Comment: You can intuit your way to other functions that work with this method as well - e.g. another is $f_n(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-[2^n (x - 0.5)]^2}$, based on the idea of a gaussian as a "nascent" delta function and ignoring the normalization as irrelevant for this case. The peak in the middle gets shorter but gets sharper much faster, so the derivatives on its sides pop out like bulging eyeezzzzz...... hggeeeeeggggghhhhieeeeee.......